# How to identify TF binding motifs?

Tags: fasta, homer

I have DNA sequences from a single gecko species for a set of genes (SULF1, SOX9, SAL1), I wanted to compare the putative promoter sequences for each gene, and compare them to the promoter regions of other related species. Would something like HOMER work for say finding TF binding motifs in around 20 different sequences for 20 different species, or would I need a larger dataset?